# Acabo de crear un archivo ejecutable en python pero no abre en otros ordenadores solo en el mío

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pip, exe

```
from tkinter import font, messagebox
from tkinter import *
import random

def obvio():
    messagebox.showinfo(message="Lo sabía", title="")

def button_hover(event):
    x = random.randint(10, 400)
    y = random.randint(10, 400)
    my_button_2.place(x=x, y=y)

def exit_(event):
    x = random.randint(10, 400)
    y = random.randint(10, 400)
    my_button_2.place(x=x,y=y)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/ATXSTREAM01/Desktop/love/amor.ico')
root.configure(background='#FFC7FA')
root.title('RESPONDEME')

label_0 = Label(root, text="Quieres ser mi novia?", bg='#FFC7FA', fg='black', width=0, font=("BubbleGum", 30))
label_0.place(x=90, y=60)

my_button_1 = Button(root, text="SI", width=5, height=1, font=("BubbleGum", 30), bg='#FF4141', fg='white', command=obvio)
my_button_1.place(x=100, y=220)

my_button_2 = Button(root, text="NO", width=5, height=1, font=("BubbleGum", 30), bg='#FF4141', fg='white')
my_button_2.place(x=350, y=220)

my_button_2.bind("<Enter>", button_hover)
my_button_2.bind("<Leave>", exit_)

root.mainloop()
```

> 

es el programa : quieres ser mi novia?, en mi ordenador se ejecuta sin problemas, ya lo cambie de .py a .exe, pero intente pasarlo a un amigo para que lo pruebe y sale error o solo se cierra. Quisiera saber que debo hacer para poder enviarlo y que pueda correr en distintos ordenadores.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo pasaste de .py a .exe?

Comment: seguí tutos en yt, no si necesites saber como lo hice por tu respuesta, aquí te dejo el video que me ayudo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vr9vl0qlggE&t=475s&ab_channel=pildorasinformaticas

Answer (score 2):

la ruta de la imagen es absoluta y otros ordenadores no la tienen
debes usar una imagen en base 64 ejemplo

primero conviertes la imagen o usas una web online

```
import base64

with open("path/to/image.png", "rb") as image_file:
    image_data_base64_encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()) 
    print(image_data_base64_encoded_string)
```

ahora con el texto resultante creas una variable

```
image_data_base64_encoded_string= "StringBase64"
imagen = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data_base64_encoded_string)
```

Comment: No entiendo por que todo el lio de cargarlo a base 64 si PhotoImage tiene el parametro file que sirve para abrir una imagen en determinado directorio. De cualquier modo, ya estás intentando abrir la imagen con un directorio.

Comment: como programador debemos aprender a leer.. la pregunta y  la respuesta.. notaras que habla de que no le carga en otros ordenadores convirtiendola a base64 no necesita un path solo el string que quedara dentro del codigo siempre.. si desea ir pc por pc a agreagar la imagen tu solucion es perfecta!

Comment: Pues tu solución abre un archivo en modo "rb". No muestras especificamente como el OP debe "poner dentro del código" la imagen. Además, yo optaría por rutas relativas o rutas absolutas que toman de base la ubicación del exe.

Answer (score -1):

Una vez que terminas tu aplicativo, es necesario empaquetarlo para ser distribuido, aquí te dejo un link para que veas como hacerlo.

[https://www.3engine.net/wp/2016/05/como-preparar-y-distribuir-un-paquete-python/#:~:text=setup.py%20setuptools%20deja%20tu%20aplicaci%C3%B3n%20o%20m%C3%B3dulo%20preparado,construir%2C%20instalar%2C%20actualizar%20y%20desinstalar%20paquetes%20de%20Python](https://www.3engine.net/wp/2016/05/como-preparar-y-distribuir-un-paquete-python/#:%7E:text=setup.py%20setuptools%20deja%20tu%20aplicaci%C3%B3n%20o%20m%C3%B3dulo%20preparado,construir%2C%20instalar%2C%20actualizar%20y%20desinstalar%20paquetes%20de%20Python).

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.